# jQuery UI button icon: e.extra.match is not a function

Tags: html, jquery-ui, button, widget, icons

trying to use an icon in a [jquery-ui button widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear"></span>
    <button id="btn">Button</button>


<script>

    $("#btn").button({
        icon: {icon: "ui-icon-gear"}
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I got the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: e.extra.match is not a function
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._classes (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:8956)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._toggleClass (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:9473)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._addClass (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:9265)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._updateIcon (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:8:17888)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._updateIcon (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._enhance (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:8:17358)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._enhance (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:8:17057)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4326)

Any hint on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to preserve the "Button" text in your button? Or are you trying to affect an icon-only button?

Comment: @Ito Pizarro The final goal is to have an icon-only button, but I got that error regardless if the button is with or without text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redundantly duplicating your configuration object.

```
$( [selector] ).button( {
    icon: "ui-icon-gear" // you don't have to pass `icon` its own object here
} );
```

And, to suppress the "Button" text, you can add the `showLabel: false` property.
Also, your `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear"></span>` is unnecessary to render the icon within the `button`.

```js
$("#button-example-1").button({
  icon: "ui-icon-gear"
});
$("#button-example-2").button({
  icon: "ui-icon-gear",
  showLabel: false
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="button-example-1">Button with icon and text</button>
<button id="button-example-2">Icon only button</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, the code snippet on jquery docs confused me. The span icon was just to show that the jquery icon classes worked correctly